# Realm query result always null

Tags: java, android, realm

i've got a Realm DB containing some Item. I've populated the DB getting info from my online DB but when i try to execute a query on DB it gives always null data.

Im sure that data from DB is not null.

I've populated the DB as official site shows.

Here where i use my query's result:

```
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    Item result = ItemHandler.getItem(mDataset.get(position));

    Picasso.get().load(result.getImg()).resize(100,100).onlyScaleDown().centerCrop().into(holder.itemImage);
    holder.itemName.setText(result.getName());
    holder.itemValue.setText(result.getSell_value());

    //TODO when clicked open a dialog

}
```

Query method:

```
public static Item getItem(int id){

    Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
    return realm.where(Item.class).equalTo("id", id).findFirst();

}
```

Item class:

```
public class Item extends RealmObject {

private int id;
private String name;
private String description;
private int img;
private int buff_health;
private int buff_damage;
private int buff_armor;
private int buy_value;
private int sell_value;

public int getBuy_value() {
    return buy_value;
}

public void setBuy_value(int buy_value) {
    this.buy_value = buy_value;
}

public int getSell_value() {
    return sell_value;
}

public void setSell_value(int sell_value) {
    this.sell_value = sell_value;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}

public int getImg() {
    return img;
}

public void setImg(int img) {
    this.img = img;
}

public int getBuff_health() {
    return buff_health;
}

public void setBuff_health(int buff_health) {
    this.buff_health = buff_health;
}

public int getBuff_damage() {
    return buff_damage;
}

public void setBuff_damage(int buff_damage) {
    this.buff_damage = buff_damage;
}

public int getBuff_armor() {
    return buff_armor;
}

public void setBuff_armor(int buff_armor) {
    this.buff_armor = buff_armor;
}
}
```

EDIT: here is where i store my data:

```
public static void addToDB(List<ItemMaster> itemMasterList, Resources resource){

    Realm myRealm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();

    for(int i = 0; i < itemMasterList.size(); i++){

        myRealm.beginTransaction();

        Item item = myRealm.createObject(Item.class);
        item.setId(itemMasterList.get(i).getId());
        item.setName(itemMasterList.get(i).getName());
        item.setDescription(itemMasterList.get(i).getDescription());
        item.setBuff_armor(itemMasterList.get(i).getBuff_armor());
        item.setBuff_damage(itemMasterList.get(i).getBuff_damage());
        item.setBuff_health(itemMasterList.get(i).getBuff_health());
        item.setBuy_value(itemMasterList.get(i).getBuy_value());
        item.setSell_value(itemMasterList.get(i).getSell_value());
        item.setImg(resource.getIdentifier("item_" + itemMasterList.get(i).getId(), "drawable", null));

        myRealm.commitTransaction();

    }

    myRealm.close();

    //TODO check this, last watch, not saving

}
```

Comment: Are you saving the data and querying it using the same thread? I think otherwise `Realm.getDefaultInstance();` will return different instance per thread. You can call `Realm.getGlobalInstanceCount(Realm.getDefaultConfiguration());` to see how many instances you have.

Comment: @HedShafran I notice now that i store data in an AsyncTask, and try to get it from a normal Thread. How can i access the same Instance ?

Comment: So If you're using an `AsyncTask`, save the data in `onPostExecute`

Comment: I've moved the storing part in the same class where i execute Query but it keeps returning null values

Comment: I've added the part where i store data in my question.

Comment: If `id` is annotated with `@PrimaryKey`, then you need to use `realm.createObject(Item.class, id)`.

Comment: It is not annotated with @PrimaryKey